# why update-ca-certificates deletes all my CA Certificates?

Tags: 20.04, updates, certificates

Every time I update the OS or if I execute manually the ca-certificate update on my 3 pc, I get:

```
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/f249de83.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/e2799e36.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/4bfab552.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/T-TeleSec_GlobalRoot_Class_3.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/a3418fda.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/emSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_G3.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/116bf586.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/cc450945.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/e73d606e.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/ee64a828.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/UCA_Global_G2_Root.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/emSign_Root_CA_-_G1.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/080911ac.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_G3.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/QuoVadis_Root_CA_3_G3.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/D-TRUST_Root_Class_3_CA_2_2009.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/607986c7.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/c01cdfa2.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/68dd7389.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/SwissSign_Gold_CA_-_G2.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_ECC_RootCA_2015.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/5ad8a5d6.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/6d41d539.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/E-Tugra_Certification_Authority.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/0f5dc4f3.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Amazon_Root_CA_3.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R6.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/DigiCert_Trusted_Root_G4.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/GTS_Root_R1.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Security_Communication_Root_CA.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G2.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/03179a64.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/4042bcee.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/DigiCert_Global_Root_CA.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/7d0b38bd.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Buypass_Class_2_Root_CA.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/CA_Disig_Root_R2.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/9b5697b0.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/064e0aa9.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/1e08bfd1.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Trustis_FPS_Root_CA.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/TrustCor_RootCert_CA-2.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/c089bbbd.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_RootCA_2015.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Izenpe.com.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/DigiCert_High_Assurance_EV_Root_CA.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Autoridad_de_Certificacion_Firmaprofesional_CIF_A62634068.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/OISTE_WISeKey_Global_Root_GC_CA.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Atos_TrustedRoot_2011.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/e868b802.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R3.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/9c2e7d30.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/57bcb2da.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority_-_G2.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/AffirmTrust_Networking.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/6fa5da56.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Starfield_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/40193066.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/54657681.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/USERTrust_ECC_Certification_Authority.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/0b1b94ef.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/GTS_Root_R3.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/773e07ad.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/dd8e9d41.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/f3377b1b.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/988a38cb.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/930ac5d2.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/cd8c0d63.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/e18bfb83.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/4304c5e5.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Starfield_Class_2_CA.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/TWCA_Global_Root_CA.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Cybertrust_Global_Root.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/4a6481c9.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/5a4d6896.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Buypass_Class_3_Root_CA.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/QuoVadis_Root_CA_2.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/OISTE_WISeKey_Global_Root_GB_CA.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/COMODO_ECC_Certification_Authority.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/1001acf7.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/1636090b.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/706f604c.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/062cdee6.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/COMODO_RSA_Certification_Authority.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/IdenTrust_Public_Sector_Root_CA_1.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/QuoVadis_Root_CA_3.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/8cb5ee0f.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/UCA_Extended_Validation_Root.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/fe8a2cd8.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/1d3472b9.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/SecureTrust_CA.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/2e5ac55d.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/2ae6433e.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/ISRG_Root_X1.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/8867006a.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/32888f65.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Entrust.net_Premium_2048_Secure_Server_CA.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/09789157.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/GlobalSign_Root_CA.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Amazon_Root_CA_2.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_CA.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/2c543cd1.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/AC_RAIZ_FNMT-RCM.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/TrustCor_RootCert_CA-1.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/certSIGN_Root_CA_G2.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/e-Szigno_Root_CA_2017.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Certigna_Root_CA.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Staat_der_Nederlanden_Root_CA_-_G3.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Go_Daddy_Class_2_CA.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/QuoVadis_Root_CA_2_G3.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Hongkong_Post_Root_CA_1.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Network_Solutions_Certificate_Authority.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/NAVER_Global_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/GlobalSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_R5.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Certum_Trusted_Network_CA_2.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Trustwave_Global_ECC_P256_Certification_Authority.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Certum_Trusted_Network_CA.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/VeriSign_Universal_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/GDCA_TrustAUTH_R5_ROOT.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Hongkong_Post_Root_CA_3.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/c47d9980.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Sonera_Class_2_Root_CA.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/emSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_C3.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Trustwave_Global_ECC_P384_Certification_Authority.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/ePKI_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/DST_Root_CA_X3.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/SSL.com_Root_Certification_Authority_RSA.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Amazon_Root_CA_4.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/e113c810.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/c28a8a30.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/9c8dfbd4.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/GTS_Root_R4.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/c01eb047.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Global_Chambersign_Root_-_2008.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R2.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/TrustCor_ECA-1.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Go_Daddy_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Trustwave_Global_Certification_Authority.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/8d86cdd1.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Amazon_Root_CA_1.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/4b718d9b.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_RootCA_2011.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Certigna.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/4f316efb.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Microsoft_ECC_Root_Certificate_Authority_2017.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/SZAFIR_ROOT_CA2.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/D-TRUST_Root_Class_3_CA_2_EV_2009.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/EC-ACC.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/SSL.com_EV_Root_Certification_Authority_RSA_R2.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority_-_EC1.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/2b349938.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/SecureSign_RootCA11.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/COMODO_Certification_Authority.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/48bec511.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Microsoft_RSA_Root_Certificate_Authority_2017.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/USERTrust_RSA_Certification_Authority.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/QuoVadis_Root_CA_1_G3.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/emSign_Root_CA_-_C1.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/TUBITAK_Kamu_SM_SSL_Kok_Sertifikasi_-_Surum_1.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/9d04f354.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/CFCA_EV_ROOT.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/AffirmTrust_Premium.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/cd58d51e.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/ff34af3f.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/certSIGN_ROOT_CA.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/SSL.com_Root_Certification_Authority_ECC.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Starfield_Services_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/cbf06781.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/3e45d192.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Staat_der_Nederlanden_EV_Root_CA.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/QuoVadis_Root_CA.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Microsec_e-Szigno_Root_CA_2009.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/106f3e4d.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/DigiCert_Global_Root_G3.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/8160b96c.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/AffirmTrust_Commercial.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/IdenTrust_Commercial_Root_CA_1.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/ad088e1d.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/ef954a4e.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Security_Communication_RootCA2.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/TWCA_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/ca6e4ad9.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority_-_G4.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/DigiCert_Global_Root_G2.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/d853d49e.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/02265526.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/TeliaSonera_Root_CA_v1.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Comodo_AAA_Services_root.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/SSL.com_EV_Root_Certification_Authority_ECC.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Chambers_of_Commerce_Root_-_2008.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/f0c70a8d.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/dc4d6a89.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/b1159c4c.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/ACCVRAIZ1.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/XRamp_Global_CA_Root.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/T-TeleSec_GlobalRoot_Class_2.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Actalis_Authentication_Root_CA.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/SwissSign_Silver_CA_-_G2.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/NetLock_Arany_=Class_Gold=_Főtanúsítvány.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/349f2832.0
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/GlobalSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_R4.pem
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/b204d74a.0
Doing .
link ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem -> 0c31d5ce.0
1 added, 10 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

Warning: there was a problem reading the certificate file /etc/ssl/certs/NAVER_Global_Root_Certification_Authority.pem. Message:
/etc/ssl/certs/NAVER_Global_Root_Certification_Authority.pem (No existe el archivo o el directorio)
Removing debian:GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem
Removing debian:GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority.pem
Removing debian:GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.pem
Removing debian:GeoTrust_Universal_CA.pem
Removing debian:GeoTrust_Universal_CA_2.pem
Removing debian:VeriSign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G4.pem
Removing debian:VeriSign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G5.pem
Removing debian:thawte_Primary_Root_CA.pem
Removing debian:thawte_Primary_Root_CA_-_G2.pem
Removing debian:thawte_Primary_Root_CA_-_G3.pem
done.
done.
```

what is this?

```
bash: /opt/systemScripts/sBin/test.sh: No such file or directory
```

1. I did not modify anything that execute that.
2. Why it removes my authorities certificates?
3. Why ALL my certificates are removed? (included default from OS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was that, some of my scripts creates a wrong file at /usr/**s**bin/test, and that program /usr/bin/test (without **s**) is used by ca-certificate, so it fail (priorities execute my script instead of original test), and delete the "wrong/failed" certificates